# GoogleMap and ListView on the same sreen

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I want to make screen like in top side show google map and the one filtering form and then last show vertical listview.
i have many try but map is not vertical scrolling, its take listview's scrolling.

and how i can add zoom plus and zoom minus buttin in map

my widget tree is like .. mapView is GoogleMap widget.

```
 return ListView(
         children: <Widget>[
           SizedBox(height: mapHeight, child: MapView()),
            ListView(
             physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
             shrinkWrap: true,
             children: <Widget>[
               getForm(context),
               getWorkerList(context)
             ],
           ) ,
         ],
       );
```

another try like below but not get proper output

```
 return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      child: ListView(
        //i want to disable listview scrolling when scroll on map
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 300,
            child: MapView1()),
        ],
      )),
  getForm(context),
  getWorkerList(context)
  ],
);
```

MapView code

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  GoogleMap(
     mapToolbarEnabled: true,
     myLocationEnabled: true,
     zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
     scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
     rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
     myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
     gestureRecognizers: Set()
       ..add(
           Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
       ..add(
         Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
             () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()),
       )
       ..add(
         Factory<HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
             () => HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer()),
       )
       ..add(
         Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
             () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
       ),
     initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
       target: LatLng(41.143029, -8.611274),
       zoom: _currentZoom,
     ),
     markers: _markers,
     onMapCreated: (controller) => _onMapCreated(controller),
     onCameraMove: (position) => _updateMarkers(position.zoom),
            );
  }
```

Desired result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can use bottomSheet

Comment: but we need only in listview or column

Comment: Did you tried using inside ListView or Column ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

add this line to your googlemap widget

```
gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<EagerGestureRecognizer>(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())),
```

like this

```
GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(double.parse(widget.latitude), double.parse(widget.longitude)),
            zoom: 15.4746,
          ),
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _controller.complete(controller);
          },
          gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<EagerGestureRecognizer>(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())),
)
```

Comment: Black magic! You saved me!